# SSRS / MySQL / Stored Procedure with parameters through ODBC

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, odbc

We are using SQL Server 2012 and MySQL 6 and though I can write a SQL statement directly in the Dataset window, I cannot seem to get a MySQL Stored Procedure to work by passing parameters via CALL:

Actuaaly my problem is
 either SSRS or the ODBC driver is having a problem sending/receiving the parameter value.

Other attempts at syntax:
      call shop.GetRegions() ,
      call shop.GetRegions(?) ,
      call shop.GetRegions(regid) ,
      call shop.GetRegions(@regid)

None of these worked.

If I call the procedure with a hard coded value i.e.  call shop.GetRegions(5) - it works.

Again, if the stored procedure has no parameters it works fine.

Can anyone give me any real direction on this issue.  A sample of the correct syntax or a step by step example would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "None of these worked." - what happened, did you get an error message or did it just not return any results

Comment: Actually In my 'mysql' stored procedure have two parameters start date and enddate  . My problem is How to call these sp in SSRS report through ODBC Datasource.          Can anyone tell me the syntax of callling sp in ssrs.

Comment: I am not getting parameters in Report level  ..               I called like this call SP_Name('@parameter1','@parameter2')

Comment: Hi Nathan, I called   call SP_Name('@parameter1','@parameter2') ...but am not return any result in the Report.

Comment: SSRS may not automatically map report parameters to a MySQL data source, have you tried manually editing the parameters of the *Dataset* to add a mapping from the report parameters to the stored procedure parameters?

Comment: Hi Nathan,I tried manually create parameters also, its not working.  Is Any otherway to calling mysql stored procedures in SSRS ?

Comment: Hi,

Finally i got solution.

we should create linked server in SSMS from MYSQL then only we will call the stored procedure.

syntax to call stored procedure:

EXEC ('CALL GASP_sales_aps(?, ?)', @dt_start, @dt_end) AT MySQL  (Linked Server Name)

GASP_sales_aps ---->procedure Name

(@dt_start,@dt_end)------>   are parameters .

Comment: Great! Can you add your solution as the answer to your question, that will help other people looking for similar answers.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got solution struggled by couple of days.
We should create linked server in SSMS from MYSQL and then only we need to call the stored procedure. 
Syntax to call stored procedure:

```
EXEC ('CALL GASP_sales_aps(?, ?)', @dt_start, @dt_end)AT MySQL(Linked Server Name)
```

**GASP_sales_aps ---->procedure Name**

**(@dt_start,@dt_end)------> are parameters .**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a linked server you can

1. set the dataset type to be Text
2. set the query to

   > ="exec GASP_sales_aps'," & Parameters!@parameter1.Value & "','" & Parameters!@parameter1.Value &"'"

Answer (score 0):

@RegBes is correct instead of linked server set the dataset type to Text. small workaround in syntax add the parenthesis and instead of exec need to use call for mysql.

```
="call GASP_sales_aps('," & Parameters!@parameter1.Value & "','" & Parameters!@parameter1.Value &"')"
```